# dynamic array advantage in certain(simple) example

Tags: c++, arrays

I have seen examples showing the basic usage of dynamic arrays like that

```
int main()
{

   int n;
   int *array;       

   std::cin >> n;

   array = new int[n];

   delete [] array;

   return 0;

}
```

but I can do

```
int main()
{

   int n;

   std::cin >> n;

   int array[n];

   return 0;

}
```

to create static array and let the user define its size. So what advantage of dynamic arrays that example shows?

Comment: The second is not valid C++.

Comment: You can? The index supplied is supposed to be constant, so it shouldn't really work. Aside from that, it has to do with the stack and the heap, which you can read more about nearly everywhere (including here on stack overflow).

Comment: "The second is not valid C++" but it compiles without warnings -gcc 4.8.1

Comment: _"but it compiles..."_  That will not tell you if it's valid C++.  _Compiler extensions_ and all...

Answer (score 2):

The first is poor C++ coding style.  A better solution is:

```
int main() {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;

  std::vector<int> array(n); // or std::unique_ptr<int[]> array( new int[n] );

  return 0;
}
```

which gives you RAII and clear buffer ownership.

The second example you give is not legal C++.  Your compiler may support it as an extension (either because of the future proposal, because of compatibility with C, or for whatever other reason).  There are proposals to add this syntax to a future C++ version.  It is legal C under the current standard, but C++ is not a superset of C.

Under the proposed version, `int array[n]` creates an array in automatic storage that goes out of scope when the current scope ends.  This means it must exist within a scope, and it cannot exceed that scope's lifetime -- the `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr` solutions above can have the buffer outlive the current scope.

Another solution for a future version of C++ is `std::dynarray<int>` which represents a value-semantics buffer.  Like `int array[n]` its buffer cannot live beyond the end of the current scope, but at least it can be returned from a function (and its data copied) without jumping through hoops.

One other problem with automatic storage solutions is that stack space is sometimes much more limited than heap space (the free store).  So sticking large amounts of stuff on the stack is dangerous.  In addition, there are ways to catch allocations failures on the heap, but protection against stack overflow in C/C++ is less robust.

A final problem with `int array[n]` is that C style arrays have strange semantics when passed to functions and the like (with their pointer-decay) that sometimes gets in the way.

Comment: note: it's optional under the current C standard . C11 changed its status from required to optional.

Answer (score 1):

Variable length arrays are a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html). So, your code isn't portable. It would be a good practice to pick an appropriate STL container, unless the overhead is absolutely unacceptable. In that case, stick to your first code snippet.